# Question on the inequality in the definition of contraction mapping

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

The following definition is taken from Wikipedia:

In mathematics, a $\textit{contraction mapping}$, or $\textit{contraction}$ or $\textit{contractor}$, on a metric space $ (M, d) $ is a function $ f $ from $ M $ to itself, with the property that there is some real number $ 0 \leq k < 1 $ such that for all $ x $ and $ y $ in $ M $,

$ d(f(x), f(y)) \leq k d(x, y). $

My question is, why it cannot be $ d(f(x), f(y)) = k d(x, y)$ instead? I suppose the inequality sign in the original definition serves some non-trivial purpose but I don't know what is that. I tried but failed to find a counter-example to my alternative definition without the inequality.

Comment: A counterexample to a definition ?

Comment: @NaNoS a counterexample to my alternative definition (I supposed it is wrong but not sure why).

Comment: Your question is not clear. A counterexample showing that "your alternative definition"  (1) is not equivalent to the one  (2) you quoted? Of course, $(2)\implies(1)$. Are you looking for a function $f$ satisfying (1) but not (2)? But if so, why did you write "without the inequality" at the end of your post? And please, **show your attempts even if they failed.** This will help us to understand what you need.

Comment: Maybe a specific example is helpful: if you use your definition to state a new "Sam-Banach fixed point theorem for Sam-contraction mappings", this theorem will be *less useful* than the normal Banach fixed point theorem for normal contraction mappings. In a world where nobody ever realised that you can prove the Banach fixed point theorem in such generality, we wouldn't be able to use it to prove [Picard-Lindelof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem)!

Comment: @AnneBauval because I was trying to find a counter-example, the failed cases are just those that work for both versions of the definition (but now I already can see what I was missing from the accepted answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In math, we often try to construct definitions in a way so that
(A) we can prove meaningful results about all objects which satisfy the definition, and (B) the definition has the *widest* scope possible. For many results which involve contraction mappings, the proofs work if we have either $\leq$ or $=$ in the "definition" of a contraction mapping. However, the proofs which use the $\leq$ definition (which includes the case of $=$) are stronger results, since it is a statement about a much wider class of objects.

For example, consider $f(x)=x^2$ on $M=[0,0.5]$ This is a contraction with $k=0.5$, but it does not always satisfy the definition with equality. For instance, strictness of the inequality is demonstrated by $$d\big(f(0.1),f(0.2)\big)= |0.01-0.04|=0.03 < 0.05 = k \cdot d(0.1,0.2).$$

This is an example of a contraction mapping (in the traditional sense), but it does not satisfy the condition with equality. So all of the proofs we know and love about contraction mappings would not apply to this example if we used the stricter definition which only relied on "$=$".

Comment: but this map does have a fixed point right

Comment: I got it. Thank you. Basically with = only is too restrictive in the sense that it precludes many f that can lead to a fixed point (like the one you showed).

Comment: Exactly! And just for completeness, yes $f(0)=0$ is its fixed point.